# Excel Object Required

Tags: excel

I'm trying to add record to my worksheet using a form. When I click on the command button (Add Record) it prompted me "required object".

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim AddNew As Range
    Set wks = Sheet1
    Set AddNew = wks.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = TextBoxProductCode.Text 
    AddNew.Offset(0, 1).Value = TextBoxProductName.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 2).Value = TextBoxDescription.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 3).Value = TextBoxCustomerName.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 4).Value = TextBoxBottlesRequested.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 5).Value = TextBoxDateReceived.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 6).Value = TextBoxRequestedETD.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 7).Value = TextBoxEnteredBy.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 8).Value = TextBoxDate.Text    
End Sub
```

Comment: Who promted you `required object`? The IDE? Excel? And how was it displayed? Maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are offsetting twice?

Comment: I am new to visual Basics so im kind of out of track, but if you guys can help me that would be great

Comment: Hey Marvin, so i run the form, click on the add record button then i get that prompted

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot "see" the variables like ***TextBoxProductCode*** since they are not `Dim`'ed nor `Set` in the sub's scope.

Comment: so what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

@Joe, Make sure to  check the name of your textboxes. it should be same on your code.
Also, try to change the range of your addnew.

instead of:

```
`Set AddNew = wks.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`
```

try the below code:

```
`Set AddNew = wks.Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`
```

so it will start from A1 column and add the value on the first blank cell.